# How can I extract specific keywords from one column into a new column in Excel?

Tags: excel

How can I extract specific keywords from one column into a new column in Excel? For ex.: If I have a "Notes" column with lengthy text, but I know some of those notes contain a key phrase (e.g., assign to Bob, and I want to extrat Bob into a new column) how could I do this?

I've used conditional formatting to highlight the word I want to extract.

Comment: `SEARCH`  may be useful.

Comment: You have used conditional formatting to highlight the word you want to extract? How?